# Proguard rules with Excel fail on release build - Android

Tags: android, apache-poi, proguard

**Edit: Updated with dependencies**

**Edit 2: Updated to show the function causing the error**

Dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '3.1.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.2.2'
implementation("it.skrape:skrapeit:1.2.2")
```

In my proguard file I have the following:

```
-keep class org.apache.poi.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.** {*;}
-keep class com.fasterxml.** {*;}
-keep class com.microsoft.schemas.** {*;}
-keep class org.openxmlformats.** {*;}
-keep class org.openxmlformats.schemas.** {*;}
-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.** {*;}
```

This works fine in the debug build, but causes a crash when axcessing one of the methods in the release build.

The full stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Unknown Source:0)
    at j7.a.a(SourceFile:2)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook.<clinit>(SourceFile:1)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook$Factory.newInstance(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(SourceFile:1)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(SourceFile:5)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(SourceFile:1)
    at com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker.shared.utils.FileUtils.pointsToWorkBook(SourceFile:2)
    at com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker.shared.utils.FileUtils.dataPointsToExcelFile(SourceFile:1)
    at f9.k.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:17)
    at sa.a.resumeWith(SourceFile:3)
    at qd.o0.run(SourceFile:18)
    at xd.a$a.run(SourceFile:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load nodeToCursor: verify that xbean.jar is on the classpath
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildMethod(SourceFile:4)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeMethod(Unknown Source:18)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeToCursorMethod(Unknown Source:4)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(SourceFile:11)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Unknown Source:0) 
    at j7.a.a(SourceFile:2) 
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook.<clinit>(SourceFile:1) 
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook$Factory.newInstance(Unknown Source:0) 
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(SourceFile:1) 
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(SourceFile:5) 
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(SourceFile:1) 
    at com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker.shared.utils.FileUtils.pointsToWorkBook(SourceFile:2) 
    at com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker.shared.utils.FileUtils.dataPointsToExcelFile(SourceFile:1) 
    at f9.k.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:17) 
    at sa.a.resumeWith(SourceFile:3) 
    at qd.o0.run(SourceFile:18) 
    at xd.a$a.run(SourceFile:14) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.nodeToCursor [interface org.w3c.dom.Node]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2103)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1724)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildMethod(SourceFile:1)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeMethod(Unknown Source:18) 
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeToCursorMethod(Unknown Source:4) 
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(SourceFile:11) 
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Unknown Source:0) 
    at j7.a.a(SourceFile:2) 
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook.<clinit>(SourceFile:1) 
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook$Factory.newInstance(Unknown Source:0) 
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(SourceFile:1) 
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(SourceFile:5) 
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(SourceFile:1) 
    at com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker.shared.utils.FileUtils.pointsToWorkBook(SourceFile:2) 
    at com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker.shared.utils.FileUtils.dataPointsToExcelFile(SourceFile:1) 
    at f9.k.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:17) 
    at sa.a.resumeWith(SourceFile:3) 
    at qd.o0.run(SourceFile:18)
```

The function causing the error:

```
    fun pointsToWorkBook(
        dataPoints: List<DataPoint>, textPoints: List<TextPoint>, trackedElement: TrackedElement,
        isText: Boolean, context: Context
    ): Workbook {
        initPoi()
        val workbook = XSSFWorkbook()
        val sheet = workbook.createSheet(stringToValidFileName(trackedElement.title))

        val titleCell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0)
        titleCell.setCellValue(trackedElement.title)
        val font = workbook.createFont()
        font.bold = true
        val titleStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()
        titleStyle.setFont(font)
        titleCell.cellStyle = titleStyle

        val linkFont = workbook.createFont()
        linkFont.underline = Font.U_SINGLE
        linkFont.color = IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex()
        val anyTrackerCell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0)
        val anyTrackerString = XSSFRichTextString("Tracking with AnyTracker")
        anyTrackerString.applyFont(14, 24, linkFont)
        anyTrackerCell.setCellValue(anyTrackerString)
        val link = workbook.creationHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL)
        link.address = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shervinkoushan.anyTracker"
        anyTrackerCell.hyperlink = link

        val infoCell = sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0)
        val trackedInfo = StringUtils.getTrackedInfo(trackedElement, context)
        infoCell.setCellValue(trackedInfo)
        trackedElement.websiteBundle?.websiteUrl?.let { url ->
            val websiteLink = workbook.creationHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL)
            websiteLink.address = url
            infoCell.hyperlink = websiteLink
            val richString = XSSFRichTextString(StringUtils.getTrackedInfo(trackedElement, context))
            val startIndex = trackedInfo.indexOf(url)
            richString.applyFont(startIndex, startIndex + url.length, linkFont)
            infoCell.setCellValue(richString)
        }
        val header = sheet.createRow(5)
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Date")
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 23 * 260)
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 16 * 260)

        val dateFormat = workbook.creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
        val dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()
        dateStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN)
        dateStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN)
        dateStyle.dataFormat = dateFormat
        dateStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)
        val bottomDateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()
        bottomDateStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN)
        bottomDateStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN)
        bottomDateStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN)
        bottomDateStyle.dataFormat = dateFormat
        bottomDateStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)
        val valueStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()
        valueStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN)
        val bottomValueStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()
        bottomValueStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN)
        bottomValueStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN)

        if (isText) {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(
                2, max("Value".length, textPoints.maxOfOrNull { it.text.length } ?: 0
                ) * 250
            )
            header.createCell(2).setCellValue("New text")
            textPoints.forEachIndexed { index, textPoint ->
                val row = sheet.createRow(index + 6)
                val dateCell = row.createCell(1)
                dateCell.setCellValue(Date.from(textPoint.date))
                val valueCell = row.createCell(2)
                valueCell.setCellValue(textPoint.text)
                if (index == textPoints.size - 1) {
                    dateCell.cellStyle = bottomDateStyle
                    valueCell.cellStyle = bottomValueStyle
                } else {
                    dateCell.cellStyle = dateStyle
                    valueCell.cellStyle = valueStyle
                }
            }
        } else {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(
                2, max("Value".length, dataPoints.maxOfOrNull { it.value.toString().length } ?: 0
                ) * 320
            )
            header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Value")
            dataPoints.forEachIndexed { index, dataPoint ->
                val row = sheet.createRow(index + 6)
                val dateCell = row.createCell(1)
                dateCell.setCellValue(Date.from(dataPoint.date))
                val valueCell = row.createCell(2)
                valueCell.setCellValue(dataPoint.value.toString())
                if (index == dataPoints.size - 1) {
                    dateCell.cellStyle = bottomDateStyle
                    valueCell.cellStyle = bottomValueStyle
                } else {
                    dateCell.cellStyle = dateStyle
                    valueCell.cellStyle = valueStyle
                }
            }
        }

        val headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle()
        headerStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN)
        headerStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN)
        headerStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN)
        headerStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN)
        header.getCell(1).cellStyle = headerStyle
        header.getCell(2).cellStyle = headerStyle

        return workbook
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing in my proguard file? I have tried various code snippets from Stack Overflow with no success.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.17 is over 5 years old now](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.17), what happens if you try with a vaguely recent release?

Comment: Sadly, newer versions come with other problems. I tried to use 4.10 and it crashed even without Proguard activated. So I would prefer to leave my functioning code as is, but fix this issue of course

Comment: Latest Apache POI release right now [is 5.2.3](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#5.2.3)

Comment: The problem with that release is that it requires minSDK 26, while my app has minSDK set to 23

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-keep class !com.your.package.** { *; }` to keep everything outside the files of your own package.

Comment: Yes, this works. But I obviously want something less general

Comment: could you shed some light on where in code/source you get this error. example code will help if you can.

Comment: @ddassa added the code causing the crash now.

Comment: thank you for the code update. I have tried it could not re-create the issue. I had to add `implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'` dependancy. is that something you using in your build too?

Comment: No, my related dependencies are listed above. Adding it, I got the following error: `Duplicate class javax.xml.XMLConstants found in modules jetified-htmlunit-android-2.63.0 (net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-android:2.63.0) and jetified-stax-api-1.0 (javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0)`

Comment: yes of course, i added `implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit-android', version: '2.63.0'` and it came up with same error. I didnt know you were using this library. Anyway a serious lint issue was thrown and had to exclude `common-logging`. But still cannot recreate the issue.

Comment: I was not using the library directly, but I am using `it.skrape:skrapeit:1.2.2`, which I believe uses it. Will update the description with it now. Anyway, I do not get any lint errors. How did you exclude `common-logging`? @ddassa

Comment: you can exclude duplicate libraries like this in your dependancy block; `configurations {
        all{
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error @ddassa

Answer (score 0):

These ProGuard rules work for me:

```
# Apache POI
-dontwarn com.github.luben.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.**
-dontwarn com.sun.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.brotli.**
-dontwarn org.etsi.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.**
-dontwarn org.openxmlformats.**
-dontwarn org.tukaani.**
-dontwarn org.w3.**
-keep class com.microsoft.** { *; }
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class org.etsi.** { *; }
-keep class org.openxmlformats.** { *; }
-keep class org.w3.** { *; }
-keep class org.w3c.** { *; }
-keep class org.xml.sax.** { *; }
-keep class schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.** { *; }
```

My dependencies in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
// Spreadsheets
// Don't update unless necessary. These library versions are compatible with Android 5.1 (API 22) and above
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.1")
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.1")
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.0.1") {
    exclude("org.apache.xmlbeans")
}
implementation("xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0")
```

I'm using Apache POI to create an `XLSX` spreadsheet file with an image.

If you want to exclude only those classes that really need to be kept, after the release build you can view all entry points detected by ProGuard in the file `build\outputs\mapping\release\seeds.txt`, and the removed code in `build\outputs\mapping\release\usage.txt`.